# what's wrong with WebElement and __getitem__

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

i am trying to gather the titles and the links of google search page, i am using selenium. 
i use xpath to fill the field and click the button.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path ='c:\\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get('https://www.google.com')

search_bar_xpath=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//* [@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
search_bar_xpath.send_keys('mybirthday')


search_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/center/input[1]')
search_button.click()

 search_results= browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="rso"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]')

scrap_data=[]
 for search_result in search_results:
     title = search_result.text.encode('utf8')
     link = search_result['href']
     scrap_data.append(title,link)
```

i got this message errors:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-3341663b53f6> in <module>()
      2 for search_result in search_results:
      3     title = search_result.text.encode('utf8')
----> 4     link = search_result['href']
      5     scrap_data.append(title,link)

TypeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrong at the line:

```
link = search_result['href']
```

May you need `.get_attribute` like this:

```
link = search_result.get_attribute('href')
```

Answer (score 0):

`WebElement` is not a type you can access with ['href'], it has no `__get_item__` method.
I'm not familiar with selenium but maybe you can do something like

`link = search_result.get_element_by_tag('href')`
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement